# Is adding a "use" statement in a factory class a violation of SOLID?

Tags: php, oop

I have a factory class which creates a PDF object when the method createPdf() is called. All the functions I need is contained within that object. The factory itself fulfills the SOLID principle of Single Responsibility by creating the object, right?

So, is the addition of the "use" statement below a violation of the SOLID principles? Or is that how things are supposed to be, in some ways?

```
use Vendor\Module\Pdf;

class PdfFactory
{
    public function createPdf(){
        return new Pdf(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a factory class.. it is simply a PDF generator

Comment: The code was trimmed for simplicity. There are a bunch of stuff that's happening before createPdf is invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [PHP definition](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php):

> The ability to refer to an external fully qualified name with an alias, or importing, is an important feature of namespaces. This is similar to the ability of unix-based filesystems to create symbolic links to a file or to a directory.

Your example could very well be written like:

```php
class PdfFactory
{
    public function createPdf() {
        return new \Vendor\Module\Pdf(…);
    }
}
```

So to answer your question, the `use` will never be a criteria of being in violation of any principle.